# Quote with brackets

Tags: bash

How can I quote with brackets in order to prevent Bash interpretation? I know it's possible for command substitution:

```
echo \"`echo "I will be in quote"`\"
echo \"$(echo "I will be in quote")\" # same meaning
```

Despite this, I tried using backslashes, but it's become unreadable as recursion grows.

```
echo "\"I'm in quote\""
echo %("I'm in quote") # % is what I look for
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display double quotes, you can use single quotes around the entire expression:

```
echo '"I am quoted."'
```

However, this becomes difficult to use if you want to echo single quotes as well.

To print a line or block of text that contains both single and double quotes, you can use a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), which avoids escaping quotes entirely:

```
cat << EOT 
"I am quoted."
"I'm quoted as well."
EOT
```

You don't have to use *EOT*. Any other word will do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you really want. Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
var="\"I'm in quotes\""
echo "$var"
```

```
var="I'm in quotes"
echo "\"$var\""
```

```
printf '"%s"\n' "I'm in quotes"
```

```
function echo_quoted () { printf '"%s"\n' "$*"; }
echo_quoted "I'm in quotes"
```